# Using Helmfile and HTTPProxy Custom Resource Definition

Tags: contour, helmfile

I am new to `Helmfile`, and still getting my head around it so apologies if I have just got this all wrong.  My difficulty is that I want to add Custom Resource Defintion (in this case `HttpProxy`) to a deployment of `Contour`.

This is what I have so far.  I am got `Open Service Mesh` up and running with a `helmfile` such as this:

```yaml
repositories:
- name: osm
  url: https://openservicemesh.github.io/osm
 
releases:
- name: osm
  namespace: my-namespace
  chart: osm/osm
  version: '1.2.4'
  values:
  - ./values/osm.yaml
- ...
```

and am turning on `Contour` via the option in the `./values/osm.yaml` file:

```yaml
contour:
  enabled: true
  configInline.tls:
    envoy-client-certificate:
      name: osm-contour-envoy-client-cert
```

I now want to add my CRDs such as [HttpProxy](https://projectcontour.io/docs/1.25/config/fundamentals/):

```yaml
apiVersion: projectcontour.io/v1
kind: HTTPProxy
metadata:
  name: my-proxy
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  virtualhost:
    fqdn: localhost
    corsPolicy:
      allowCredentials: true
      allowOrigin:
        - "*"
      allowMethods:
        - GET
        - POST
        - OPTIONS
      allowHeaders:
        - "*"
      exposeHeaders:
        - "*"
      maxAge: "1s" # preflight requests can be cached for 10 minutes.  
  routes:
    - conditions:
      - prefix: my-route
      services:
        - name: my-svc
          port: 8080
          validation:
            caSecret: osm-system/osm-ca-bundle
            subjectName: default.my-namespace.cluster.local
```

but I have no idea where to add this?  I know I could create a new chart for such definitions, but that feels wrong to me because the `contour` stuff should be with the `osm` definitions.

What is the right way of going about this?

Comment: In researching another question, there is an [example](https://helmfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#hooks-kubectl-and-environments) in the Helmfile documentation of running `kubectl apply` from a hook.  I don't know that it would be my preferred approach here, but it might fit your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helmfile doesn't directly create Kubernetes resources; it only installs other Helm charts.  Those can potentially be local charts.  Since Helmfile operates a release at a time, you can use its [`needs:`](https://helmfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#dag-aware-installationdeletion-ordering-with-needs) constraints to have the chart providing the CRD installed before the chart that uses it.

So I'd create a new chart, maybe with a `./charts/proxy/Chart.yaml` and the file you include in the question in `./charts/proxy/templates/httpproxy.yaml`.  You can then reference this in the `helmfile.yaml` as

```yaml
releases:
  - name: osm
    ...
  - name: proxy
    chart: ./charts/proxy
    needs:
      - osm
```

Without `needs:`, Helmfile would try installing the two charts at the same time, which wouldn't necessarily work.  If the OSM chart had an extension point where you could register additional resources, then Helm has an [internal ordering](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/484d43913f97292648c867b56768775a55e4bba6/pkg/releaseutil/kind_sorter.go) and a CustomResourceDefinition will be installed before anything else, but only within a single chart.

The other caveat is that, if you `helmfile apply -l name=proxy` to install only specific things, that won't include the `osm` dependency by default, and you may need another option like [`--include-transitive-needs`](https://helmfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#selectors-and-needs) if the dependency isn't already installed.